# I generated a console.property file from katalon studio but I can't excute through command line

Tags: katalon-studio, testautomationfx

The documentation on **Katalon** saying if run below command line after generating console. property file from test suites, it will run from the command window :

> katalon -propertiesFile="" -runMode=console

However, it says **Katalon** is not recognized as an internal or external command. What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If path of `katalon.exe` is not defined in your `PATH` variable, command above will only work if you are in `Katalon Studio` root folder, in which `katalon.exe` is located.

Comment: Yes.I can run this now.Put the prompt out command windows says:"Contains :OK Contains:(path of my testing project) overlaps the workspace of the workspace location(path of my testing project/config)"

Comment: In addition, I open my property file ,and inside the file is content :#Tue Mar 20 14:36:49 SGT 2018
deviceId=
kobitonDeviceId=
qTestDestId=
qTestDestType=
remoteWebDriverType=Selenium
remoteWebDriverUrl=                                         it was generated from my succeed test suite ,but why inside is empty ? Is it related with the command error above ?

Comment: @LacieYu : So it solved this problem. :) Try to place your project and program files of Katalon Studio to separated locations.

Comment: Thank you for the help!Really appreciate.

Comment: @LacieYu : If it is ok, than please mark answer as solution.

Comment: my vote is cast bcoz I got less than 15 reputation ,is it bcoz m a new user ?

Comment: @LacieYu : Yes, you can't upvote yet posts, but you can mark this answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a batch file with the following structure:

```
@echo off

set "qtpath=<KATALON STUDIO INSTALL DIR>"
set "execpath=%qtpath%\katalon.exe"

echo "%execpath%"

"%execpath%" <GENERATED COMMAND WITHOUT -katalon>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I solved that like:

[Environment Variables > System Variables > Path > Add Katalon.exe and Git.exe directories[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3Z9D.png)

And then, The contents of the .gitlab-ci.yml file are as follows:

> Simple .gitlab-ci.yml :

```
 run_katalon_test_suite:
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
   - echo $CI_JOB_STAGE
```

> Simple .gitlab-ci.yml to run test suit in Katalon Studio:

```
 run_katalon_test_suite:
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
 - katalon -noSplash  -runMode=console -consoleLog -noExit -projectPath="C:\Users\7713\git\turkuaz-katalon-test-project\turkuaz-katalon-test-project.prj"  -retry=1 -retryFailedTestCases=false -testSuitePath="Test Suites/cansuarslan/TS_01_CompletedTestCases"  -executionProfile="default" -browserType="Chrome"
```